# Ignoring files in SVN from parent folder

Tags: java, linux, svn, version-control

Is it possible to ignore file that is in the folder nested inside the project tree? When I'm adding such entry using "svn propedit svn:ignore ." in my root folder:

```
src/folder1/folder2/folder3/File1.java
```

SVN still displays file as unversioned(with "?" mark) and doesn't ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The svn:ignore property applies only to the contents of the folder it is set to, and not to any of its subfolders, see:
[Version Control with Subversion, Chapter "Ignoring Unversioned Items"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html)

In order to ignore File1.java, set svn:ignore on folder3 rather than on the root folder.

Comment: Thanks! My problem was that I had several different locations which contained generated source code among other sources. I solved the problem by changing location of generated source code to build directory, so I got rid of two problems: ignoring generated files and incorrect project structure :)